# ASP.NET Threading

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

The following code runs ok in Visual Studio but the website crashes when deployed to IIS7.  It appears to fail on the Application.DoEvents line, because BrowsePage.ReadyState is always uninitialised (0) and never completed (4).  It only happens when deployed to IIS (using version 7).  It is OK when debugging in Visual Sudio:

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim url As String = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
            Dim Test As Bitmap = ImageFromHtml.ConvertPage(url)
    End Sub

    Public Function ConvertPage(ByVal PageUrl As String) As Bitmap
            Me.PageUrl = PageUrl
            Dim thrCurrent As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf CreateImage))
            thrCurrent.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
            thrCurrent.Start()
            thrCurrent.Join()
            Return ConvertedImage
        End Function

    Private Sub CreateImage()
        Dim BrowsePage As New WebBrowser()
        BrowsePage.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = False
        BrowsePage.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
        BrowsePage.Navigate(PageUrl)
        AddHandler BrowsePage.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf _
WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted
        While BrowsePage.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        BrowsePage.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

I have noticed that I cannot access the webpage in the PageURL variable whilst this is running on IIS.  Therefore I believe this is a blocking problem.

WinDBG says: CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)

Comment: Hmmm, very interesting, well one thing is for sure: it appears that your website crashes when deployed on IIS7 (on the join line)! Right about now, a good thing to add to your question would be the crash error that you see when the website crashes :).

Comment: Anything else besides "CLR exception - code e0434352"?

Comment: @Lirik, there is nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried the Windows Event Log? There is often some additional information in the Application log.

Comment: It's interesting that it is crashing on a call to `Join`. Are you absolutely sure? Have you tried executing CreateImage inline instead of in separate thread?

Comment: @Brian Gideon.  thanks.  I did some further tests earlier and it appears to crash because I am trying to get a screen shot of a page in the same website.  Could this be a page locking problem? The problem does not occur when I run it locally in visual studio.  If I leave it long enough I get a screen shot that says 'navigation to the web page was cancelled'.

Comment: @Brian Gideon, I have edited the original question with more information.  The program seems to be stuck on the Application.DoEvents line i.e. the WebBrowser object is never completed (it is always in status 0 - uninitialised).  Do you have any ideas what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand why asynchrony helps your problem. Based on your code, I see no reason. If you do need the image conversion to be async, there are other potential ways to handle this, depending on why the conversion.

One pattern is set a place holder for the image and then use AJAX calls from the client side. You can then have the conversion at the end of a service endpoint. Oh, what fun it would be if HTML5 web sockets were more readily available now.

Comment: Asyncrony does not help the problem.  I am trying to capture a screen shot and as far as I can see I have two options: 1) As you say; take a screen shot on the client and post to server using AJAX, 2) Use WebBrowser server side object.  I chose option 2.  Do you know why the program hangs?

Answer (score 0):

I would not do threading in ASP.Net it causes MAJOR issues its not worth the trouble believe me been there got the shirt.

see

http://mohamedfaramawi.blogspot.com/2008/01/do-not-use-multi-threading-inside.html

I would instead setup a windows  service to query a database to know what Jobs need to be done and let the windows service do it.

Comment: Threading in any environment can cause major problems if done incorrectly or if a 3rd party API has special requirements that prevent it from working correctly. I have used various different forms of multithreading in ASP.NET and the only issues I have ever had were self inflicted.

Comment: Amen on the self infliction. What introduction to multi-threading DOESN'T come with a warning sign? :)